# Solr Suggester component for autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, solr, autosuggest

This [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1316) and this [wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) imply that there is an up-and-coming component called `org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester` for doing improved auto-complete with Solr. But I'm having trouble trying to find a release that actually has this code.

The wiki says that Solr **3.x** and **4.x** have include it; is that insider-speak for Solr **1.3** and **1.4** respectively? I'm using 1.4.1 (via Maven), and I see no such component.

Pulling the source from [here](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/job/Solr-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/artifacts/), I find it in `src/java/org/apache/solr/spelling/suggest/Suggester.java`. But it fails to build with:

```
[javac] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/user/Downloads/apache-solr-4.0-2011-02-22_08-06-33/apache-solr-4.0-2011-02-22_08-06-33/contrib/analysis-extras/build/classes

BUILD FAILED
/Users/user/Downloads/apache-solr-4.0-2011-02-22_08-06-33/apache-solr-4.0-2011-02-22_08-06-33/common-build.xml:275: /Users/user/Downloads/apache-solr-4.0-2011-02-22_08-06-33/apache-solr-4.0-2011-02-22_08-06-33/contrib/analysis-extras/lib does not exist.
```

Is there a way to get a reasonably stable Solr artifact with the `Suggester` included, preferably via Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr 3.x and 4.x are **not** 1.3 and 1.4.

1.3 and 1.4 are stable releases. 3.x and 4.x are yet unreleased. Versioning scheme changed due to Solr merging with Lucene.

If you need a 4.x build I recommend getting one from the [build server](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/job/Solr-trunk/).

Also note there are several ways to implement autocomplete with 1.4.1, see [Simple Solr schema problem for autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773753/simple-solr-schema-problem-for-autocomplet)

Comment: Thanks (again!) Mauricio. Solr is awesome, but their website & wiki need some help. :-)

Comment: So on second look, the build server you sent me to is in fact the same place I downloaded the 4.0 tarball from, and which still suffers from the "contrib/analysis-extras/lib does not exist" problem. I will keep digging to try and resolve this, but I'm wondering if it's worth the effort, or if simply using the solution in 1.4.1 is a better option. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @Caffeine Coma: ah, if it's a contrib module it's not included. However 1.4.1 works just fine for suggestions with ngrams or termscomponent.